# Is it possible to change the URL handlers at run time in Google App engine?

Tags: google-app-engine

I have two classes `MainHandler` and `ControlPanel`. The MainHandler class shows the homepage and authenticates the user. It is responsible for handling the URL `/`. After the user is successfully authenticated, I wish to have the handler changed to `ControlPanel` so that the URL stays the same but a different view is rendered. Is this possible in Google App Engine?

Below is the code that I tried (and failed):

```
class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # Show Home page

    def post(self):
        # Get user Credentials
        status=authenticate(self.request.get('username'),self.request.get('password'))
        if(status):
            global handler
            handler = ControlPanel
            self.get()
        else:
            self.get()



class ControlPanel(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.response.write("Welcome!!")

handler = MainHandler

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', handler),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: Yes, but the the question is more relevant to the web framework your using and your approach than appengine.  Some approaches use  different templates rendered rather than a different view, alternately sellecting views based on criteria other than just path (e.g. user, or logged in or anonymous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Among the simplest ways to do this is with a [Python Decorator](https://realpython.com/blog/python/primer-on-python-decorators/).

## A toy program illustrating this approach

This is a toy program, and I've abused the query string for "log in" purposes.

#### Behaviour

- Visiting `http://localhost:8080/?allow` will show `Control Panel`,
  and
- visiting `http://localhost:8080/` will display `PLEASE LOG IN` to
  the user.

#### Outline

Our toy program consists of three simple parts:

- **`require login` decorator**. We'll use this decorator on the requests that need our user to be logged in by adding `@require_login` just above the definition. If a user is authenticated (according to `user_is_authenticated`) then we will allow the request to finish as normal. If not, we return `PLEASE LOG IN` to the user.
- **`ControlPanel` class**. This is the page that requires authentication. We require authentication by adding the `@require_login` decorator, and show the string `control panel` to the user if they are logged in.
- **`user_is_authenticated` function**. This is how we check that the user is logged in or not, returning `True` or `False` based on some criteria. In our example, we check if [the query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is `allow`.

#### Implementation

```
import webapp2

def user_is_authenticated(request):

    return request.query_string == "allow"

def require_login(original):

    def check(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not user_is_authenticated(self.request):
            # show homepage and authenticate
            self.response.write('PLEASE LOG IN')
        else:
            # authenticated, let them see the requested page
            return original(self, *args, **kwargs)

    return check

class ControlPanel(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    @require_login
    def get(self):
        self.response.write('control panel')

        return

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    ('/', ControlPanel)
], debug=True)
```

#### Note

There are a million ways to for `check` to behave, and none of them is universally right. Instead of just writing a different page. You might want to redirect to a login page instead, return a `403` HTTP response, or present another version of the page.

Also, our `user_is_authenticated` function is obviously not to be used for real authentication purposes, and is unsuitable for that purpose.

### Resources

You might want to check out the following for additional ideas or clarification.

- [Google's (Python) App Engine tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction)
- [webapp2's Tutorials](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/tutorials/index.html)
- [Using the Users Service](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/usingusers)